# JavaScript image changed by keyboard

Tags: javascript, image

I have a project for school to make a game with images (instead of using Adobe Affter Effects and creating videos, that will be a better idea).

The problem is that I have 5 images as an intro and I want the user to see image 1, and if he press -> on the keyboard (right arrow) to go to the 2nd, and then go to the 3rd and so on... until 5th.

Of course, to play the game I will need onclick(); but that I will learn from a tutorial probably.

```js
let img = document.getElementById("img");
const getKey = (e) => {
  console.log(e.key);
  switch (e.key) {

    case "Right":
    case "ArrowRight":
      changeToNext();
      break;

    case "Left":
    case "ArrowLeft":
      changeToPrevious();
      break;
  }
}

const changeToNext = () => {
  if (img.src == "images/2.png") {
    img.src = "images/3.png";
  } else {
    img.src = "images/2.png";
  }
}

const changeToPrevious = () => {
  if (img.src == "images/3.png") {
    img.src = "images/2.png";
  } else {
    img.src = "images/1.png";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", getKey);
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Also, consider using `function getKey(e)` and `function changeToNext()` instead of using `const` objects because, conceptually, you're declaring functions, not objects.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please use placeholder.com or similar to add images in a [mcve]

Comment: @Dai using const to declare a function is just fine

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah - but it makes *me* feel uncomfortable :) Also, some JS language-servers (like in Visual Studio 2017) identify functions-as-variables as "objects" in IntelliSense instead of actual functions (e.g. the code-completion menu uses the field icon instead of the function icon). I appreciate that it's a superficial criticism, but I prefer not to fight my tooling.

Comment: When accessing `img.src`, you are accessing the full resolved URL of the image: and therefore, your comparison will not work correctly. I would suggest a different approach to determine which image you should be navigating to: e.g. storing a current index, and then fetching the image that corresponds to that index, instead of comparing URLs.